# Scala Hoogle equivalent?

Tags: scala, haskell, type-systems

[Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) allows you to search many standard Haskell libraries by either function name, or by approximate type signature. I find it very useful. Is there anything like Hoogle for Scala? Search in [ScalaDoc 2](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/rc-api/index.html) only finds types and packages by name.

Comment: Note Haskell also has Hayoo, which is a bit fancier, http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html

Type-based doc indexing seems to be unique to Haskell at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaladoc for Scala 3 has Hoogle-like searches feature. You can try it out [here](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/).

It uses [Inkuire](https://github.com/VirtusLab/Inkuire) search engine.

Answer (score 11):

It's a pity that it does not even have an index like javadoc. Hoogle is nicer, though.

I use a personal search engine from Google to search the Scaladocs.

A search provider (searching with site: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api) in Firefox is another way to search the docs.

Both do not work well for the Scala 2.8. release – it's not indexed well enough to be useful – and works not with all operators. For example a search for Cons `::` returns only nonsense.

Answer (score 11):

There are plans to make the Hoogle interface work with multiple languages: http://code.google.com/p/ndmitchell/issues/detail?id=45