# Practical Scala reference manual, for searching things like method names

Tags: search, scala, documentation, reference

Inspired by
[Haskell API Search Engine](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+%5ba%5d+-%3E+%5bb%5d)
I begun to wonder what is the right way of finding names of things in Scala library. 
For example let's assume I need some string substation, like search and replace. StringOps has no such thing. Google doesn't help either, because these terms are very general, and manually traversing documentation isn't much fun.

My question is, where do experts look when they are seeking a particular function?

This should be practical enough to use it in everyday work.

Comment: Isn't this question covered with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873286/scala-hoogle-equivalent ?

Comment: All that stuff can get real messy thanks to implicit conversions (that is, if you want to find implicitly defined functions/methods, too).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700331/how-to-search-for-methods-in-scaladoc-globally

Answer (score 4):

I do agree that a Hoogle like search engine for Scala would be great. Until there is such a tool, from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553909/searching-the-scala-documentation/4554181#4554181):

> I suggest using the [Reference
>   Index](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index/index-%23.html)
>
> You can see the whole thing at
>   [nightly Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html)

Comment: Sadly, this is only available for the nightly. When will the Scala people learn?

Comment: @Rafe Kettler: Here you can find Scaladoc for current stable release  http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html

Comment: @Rafe Scala 2.8.1 and older did not have a reference index, because the code that does it was not ready in time to get into that release. What do you expect "Scala people" to do?

Comment: @Daniel use the reference index for the stable build as well as the nightly. I don't see what's stopping them. @Easy that has no reference index